# Effiency of FindMember in rapidjson, compare with unorderd_map

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I know find operator in unordered_map is O(1), how about FindMember in rapidjson? Is O(1) or O(logN) in time effiency?

In one scenario, I use rapidjson::FindMember to replace unordered_map::find and find latency grows a lot, is that reasonable?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you look at the [internals](http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_internals.html) ? You're wondering between O(1) and O(log N), but the internals suggest O(N). No wonder, of course. JSON is a serialization format, not a data structure.

Comment: you mean FindMember is O(N)?

Comment: Yes. The data seems to be stored unordered, which means a linear scan is required. That's not strange, because JSON itself is unordered

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are right